# IronPython, import, and clr.AddReferenceByPartialName

Tags: .net, ironpython

In **IronPython 2.7.1**, I can import some .NET assemblies by name:

```
>>> from System.Collections import *
>>> from System.IO import *
```

Others give me an error:

```
>>> from System.Xml import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Xml
```

Doing the following fixes the error:

```
>>> import clr
>>> clr.AddReferenceByPartialName('System.Xml')
>>> from System.Xml import *
```

Why do I have to call `clr.AddReferenceByPartialName` for some assemblies but not others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some assemblies, like mscorlib.dll, are there by default.  If the documentation for the class you want says it's in mscorlib (e.g., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx), then you won't need to add a reference, otherwise you will.  It's similar to when/why you need to add references to your C# project.